# Install Openpyxl on python2.5 on Windows

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried `easy_install install openpyxl` and `python setup install`. Both failed. I also tried `easy_install openpyxl` and failed again. I include the output I get.
When I try `easy_install install openpyxl`, I get the following output:

```
Searching for install
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/install/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/install/: timed out -- Some pac
kages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'install' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages ma
y not be found!
No local packages or download links found for install
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('install')
```

When I try When I try `easy_install openpyxl` instead, I get the same output but with the word 'openpyxl' instead of 'install'.
When I try `python setup install`, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    import openpyxl  # to fetch __version__ etc
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\__init__.py",
line 32, in <module>
    from openpyxl import workbook
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\workbook.py",
line 37, in <module>
    from openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet import DumpWorksheet, save_dump
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\writer\__init_
_.py", line 29, in <module>
    from openpyxl.writer import excel
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\writer\excel.p
y", line 50, in <module>
    from openpyxl.writer.charts import ChartWriter
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\writer\charts.
py", line 27, in <module>
    from openpyxl.chart import Chart, ErrorBar
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\chart.py", lin
e 132, in <module>
    class Serie(object):
  File "D:\Python\Excel\ericgazoni-openpyxl-22d4b2135553\openpyxl\chart.py", lin
e 150, in Serie
    @color.setter
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'setter'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just download it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl), extract it and copy the `openpyxl-1.6.2\openpyxl` folder into:

```
C:\Python27\Lib
```

That should do it (that directory should be added to your `python path` by default). That assumes default python installation directory. If you've got python installed elsewhere just put the `openpyxl` into the corresponding `lib` directory.

I was a fan of `openpyxl` but now, in the hindsight, I'd recommend [driving Excel through the COM ports](http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/) (so long as you've got the license for Excel).

Comment: It didn't work either. I tried copying openpyxl-1.6.2 (and all its contents) into C:\Python25\Lib and into C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages.

Comment: Note I need to use Python 2.5.

Comment: I will give [driving Excell through the COM ports](http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/) a try!

Comment: Good luck and enjoy :D It's pretty useful and works - there's still plenty of bugs in `openpyxl` (hence I had to look for alternatives, which was COM). Virtually all the commands I've come across so far are identical as in VBA so that's a useful resource. Just the syntax is a bit different but hey, you only have to read it not write it yourself :)

Comment: @José Don't copy the **entire** folder `openpyxl-1.6.2` only `openpyxl`, which is inside, to the python `lib`.

As for using python 2.5 perhaps it's time to upgrade? Why would you use an old version? I don't use `3.x` (yet) either but the `2.7` is fine.

Comment: I use Python 2.5 because I use a library compiled on that version and I don't have access to the source code. Is there a way to use that library with a newer version of Python?

Comment: Not sure if it will work on newer versions of python if it was aimed at 2.5 (by that I mean it probably won't). But it is worth a try. You could install 2.7 in parallel, copy that library to its path, see if it works and then decide. My bet would be not to even bother with 3.X.

Comment: Well I guess that sort of answers the question. One option is to use 2.5 for that library only and a newer version for everything else.

Comment: I tried copying only the folder openpyxl and I get the second error listed in the question ('property' object has no attribute 'setter'). Anyway I'm trying using COM with good results so far.

Comment: Hmm the problem might be that this version of openpyxl is not backwards compatible with older versions of python - I've never tried installing it with older versions of python. Perhaps you could try an older version of openpyxl but I only expect it to have more bugs...

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.7 is the last version that works with Python 2.5. The decision to drop support for Python 2.5 was largely because Python 2.5 itself is no longer supported by the Python Software Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

In python3 The above mention methods are not working. Just download the openpyxl from their official web site and extract the zipped folder. And you may place that folder on your desktop. After that navigate to the openpyxl folder from the cmd.
what you have to do is execute the command

```
python setup.py install
```

and everything works fine !!!

Answer (score 0):

As [Charlie Clark stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369354/648265), you need to install an old version:

```
easy_install "openpyxl<=1.7.0"
```

or

```
pip install "openpyxl<=1.7.0"
```

the string is a [requirement specifier](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirement-specifiers).

Answer (score -2):

Just extract the folder you downloaded into C:\Python27\Lib and rename openpyxl-2.4.1 as openpyxl, then import the library as usual

Comment: this is exactly the same answer as the accepted answer.