# Reading xlsx files using Python 2.5 on Windows

Tags: python, excel

I want to be able to access `.xlsx` files from Python 2.5.

Newest version of **`xlrd`** support `.xlsx` but not Python 2.5, and older versions of xlrd support Python 2.5 but not `.xlsx`.

I can't make **`openpyxl`** work. (See related question [Install Openpyxl on python2.5 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389594/install-openpyxl-on-python2-5-on-windows))

Finally I'm trying running Excel using **`win32`**, but it collides with existing instances of Excel open, it's a bit hackish.

Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Why do you have to use 2.5? That's a very old version.

Comment: A bit trivial, but why not use 2.7?

Comment: I need to use a third party package that needs 2.5. If I switch to 2.7 returns a weird error ('bad magic number'). Maybe I could fix that problem, that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

There is one I know of : [Pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32). The latest version(build 219 from May 2014) is compatible all the way back to Python 2.3, you must just download the right version.

Now, the big trouble with Pywin32 is that it's badly documented and that without prior knowledge of COM/Visual Basic it's a pain to start rolling. Once you do and can just copy/paste macro code generated by excel it gets far easier.

This is what you want to do to get rolling :

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

If you then type, say [excel.Workbooks.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) you create a grand new excel workbook(you need to assign that to a variable to use it). So yeah, there is an alternative, but there *is* a learning curve involved.

PS :
You'll want to check out the Workbooks and Worksheets methods.